# Clear imageview on the onClick event of alertDialog

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I want to clear imageview on the onClick event of alertDialog. Im passing index of integer value  to Show_Alert method to like below. IMGS is imageView Array. there are 8 images in that array.

```
Show_Alert("Confirm", "Do you want to Delete this",true, true,1);
```

But the error is

> "Cannot refer to a non-final variable option inside an inner class
>   defined in a different method"

so I create a final int option variable

```
final int option; 
option=opt;
```

But it not work as expected. Need some help.

This is my Show_alert method

```
private void Show_Alert(String title, String message,boolean okButton, boolean cancelButton,int opt)
        {
            final int option; 
            option=opt;
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(capture_details.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle(title);
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);

            if(cancelButton==true)
            {
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            }

            if(okButton==true && option!=-1)
            {

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(option==1)
                        {
                            IMGS[option].setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                            IMGS[option].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE) ;
                            IMGS[option].setTag(null);
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
            else if(okButton==true)
            {
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    }
                });

            }
            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: Declare: "But it not work as expected." What does it do than? What does your log says? Sharing more information with us will help us a lot with finding your answer.

Comment: No errors but ImageView did not clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for an onclick listener of a dialog box below. Declare a global AlertDialog variable. Change the Show_Alert to the code below. Add the @Override method. In the .setPositiveButton you set the code for the OK button. In the .setNegativeButton you set the code of the CANCEL button. Don't know if it works instantly, but in my opinion it comes close to your solution. It some raw untested code I written out of my head.

Maybe with some help of other stackoverflow user we can make my code below work if it is not working (feel free to edit my code below). Otherwise Google will help you a lot with it.

```
private AlertDialog alertdialog;

private void Show_Alert(String title, String message) {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(capture_details.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog = builder.create();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // OK pressed
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // CANCEL pressed
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```